# Cleanest way to host a mountable network drive over the net?

Tags: windows, networking, macos

I have a fileserver for friends and we want to be able to mount it in Windows & MacOS for easy access. I don't want to expose SMB to the internet. What are my options?

Comment: Define "cleanest". No third-party software? No VPNs?

Comment: Is the fileserver an actual server (what OS?) or is it a NAS, etc? There's probably some way to limit access to local IP addresses, but difficult to go into any depth without the detail.

Comment: You need a VPN box in front of that server and then equip your friends with a VPN client to access it. It is secure but not simple.

Comment: OpenVPN or a mounted SSHFS via SSH.  Please be aware regardless of what method is utilized, the access speed will be limited to the ISP upload speed of whatever PC/server that's hosting the share.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

Use OpenVPN to create a free VPN between the VPN server and the your friends if you are worried about security.  This is the most secure option by a long shot.  How difficult it is to set up depends on your router, knowledge and NAS.

Alternatively, if If you are not worried about security or accessibility, expose the fileservers web frontend (or add a web frontend to it).  There are quite a few things you can do here, including HTTPS, requiring authentication, limiting connection IP addresses.

Another clean (but not cheap solution would be to backup your NAS to the cloud (for example using dropbox), and allow your friends to share it through that.

If the fileserver allows SSH, and you trust your friends, you may be able to port forward port 22 on your router to the fileserver (be careful with this, make sure the accounts are properly locked down), and share files over SCP (or use sshfs or equivalent)

Another solution might be to run NFS - this is normally supported by servers, and should be fairly easy to integrate with MAC, but may require additional software for Windows.  Unfortunately there are lots of versions of NFS, security could range from non-existent to pretty good depending on your versions.  Also it can be a bit tricky to allow through a firewall.